# How to debug performance problems with REST calls in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-boot, performance-testing

The good and the bad with the Spring Framework is that a lot of magic happens behind **annotations**.
I have built what I would consider a fairly `vanilla REST api` that makes **GET, PUT, and POST** on the same `URL`.When calling the `PUT` or `POST` call there is a severe `delay` between when I send the query from **Postman** to when the controller method gets control (8 to 10 seconds).   However, the `GET` call is almost instantaneous. I need a way to trace through the `spring` magic to see where the performance bottleneck is before the controller method is called.  How do I debug this code?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{collection}/branches", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<CollectionApi<BranchApi>> getBranches(@PathVariable String collection,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = ModelsController.DEF_OFFSET) Long _offset,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = ModelsController.DEF_LIMIT) Integer _limit,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String rep,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = ModelsController.DEF_SYNC) Integer _sync) {

    try {
        CollectionApi<BranchApi> branches = branchesService.getBranches(collection);
        if (branches == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Collection not found");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(branches);
    } catch (NucleusModelingException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{collection}/branches", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<CollectionApi<BranchApi>> setActiveBranch(
        @PathVariable String collection, 
        @RequestParam String branch) {

    try {
        CollectionApi<BranchApi> branches = branchesService.setActiveBranch(collection, branch);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(branches);
    } catch (NucleusModelingException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{collection}/branches", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<CollectionApi<BranchApi>> createBranch(
        @PathVariable String collection, 
        @RequestParam String branch) {

    try {
        CollectionApi<BranchApi> branches = branchesService.checkoutBranch(collection, branch);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(branches);
    } catch (NucleusModelingException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException(e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to profiling the API, the besty choice is with visual VM https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html
You can see what happens and where the time is waste